# How can I generate a unique hashcode for a string

Tags: c#

Is there any function, that gives me the same hashcode for the same string?

I'm having trouble when creating 2 different strings (but with the same content), their hashcode is different and therefore is not correctly used in a `Dictionary`.

I would like to know what `GetHashCode()` function the `Dictionary` uses when the key is a string.

I'm building mine like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
   String str = "Equip" + Equipment.ToString() + "Destiny" + Destiny.ToString();
   return str.GetHashCode();
}
```

But it's producing different results for every instance that uses this code, despite the content of the string being the same.

Comment: If the string was really the same, the hash code would be the same, too.

Comment: Are you sure the contents are equal? The documentation for String.GetHashCode clearly states that the hash code will be the same for equal strings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode.aspx

Comment: I'm quite sure String.GetHashCode returns different hashes if you restart the program.

Comment: Tsabo, while unlikely this can be possible. GetHashCode is also not required to remain the same for multiple framework versions or on different machines. (See also [here, where Eric Lippert gives an overview of hash code guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)).

Comment: Another thing that's a possible source for your dictionary problems is that you maybe forgot overriding `Equals` or giving an implementation that's consistent with `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Why do you require unique hash codes in the title? Hash collisions happen with 32 bit hashcodes. And your question body doesn't ask unique hashes at all, but just that they stay consistent over the lifetime of your program instance, which the default implementation already offers. So what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @Joey: It's not even required to remain the same for multiple runs on the *same* framework and machine. For example, it could take a random initial seed on startup - so long as it's consistent within a process, that's fine. From `object.GetHashCode`: "Note that this is true only for the current execution of an application, and that a different hash code can be returned if the application is run again."

Comment: Jon: Yep, as outlined by Eric in that blog post (hence the “unlikely, but possible”) – I just doubt System.String would do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your title asks for one thing (*unique* hash codes) your body asks for something different (*consistent* hash codes).

You claim:

> I'm having trouble when creating 2 different strings (but with the same content), their hashcode is different and therefore is not correctly used in a Dictionary.

If the strings *genuinely* have the same content, that simply won't occur. Your diagnostics are wrong somehow. Check for non-printable characters in your strings, e.g trailing Unicode "null" characters:

```
string text1 = "Hello";
string text2 = "Hello\0";
```

Here `text1` and `text2` may print the same way in some contexts, but I'd hope they'd have different hash codes.

Note that hash codes are *not* guaranteed to be unique and *can't* be... there are only 2<sup>32</sup> possible hash codes returned from `GetHashCode`, but more than 2<sup>32</sup> possible different strings.

Also note that the same content is *not* guaranteed to produce the same hash code on different runs, even of the same executable - you should not be *persisting* a hash code anywhere. For example, I believe the 32-bit .NET 4 and 64-bit .NET 4 CLRs produce different hash codes for strings. However, your claim that the values aren't being stored correctly in a `Dictionary` suggests that this is within a single process - where everything *should* be consistent.

As noted in comments, it's entirely possible that you're overriding `Equals` incorrectly. I'd also suggest that your approach to building a hash code isn't great. We don't know what the types of `Equipment` and `Destiny` are, but I'd suggest you should use something like:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 23;
    hash = hash * 31 + Equipment.GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + Destiny.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

That's the approach I usually use for hash codes. `Equals` would then look something like:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    // Reference equality check
    if (this == other)
    {
        return true;
    }         
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // Details of this might change depending on your situation; we'd
    // need more information
    if (other.GetType() != GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Adjust for your type...
    Foo otherFoo = (Foo) other;

    // You may want to change the equality used here based on the
    // types of Equipment and Destiny
    return this.Destiny == otherFoo.Destiny &&
           this.Equipment == otherFoo.Equipment;
}
```

Comment: Equipment and destiny are both enums

Comment: @RagnaRock: Right - in which case this should be fine. Is this in a class or a struct? And if it's a class, is it sealed? Either way, I doubt that you'll be able to reproduce the alleged hash mismatch.

Comment: the problem was in equals method, I thought I didnt have to override it, once I did, it worked as expected

Comment: What's the significance of 23 and 31?

Comment: @jwrightmail: They're numbers which happen to work well... 31 is useful because it can be implemented as a shift and subtract, if the JIT is smart enough. The two numbers are also primes, which I think helps..